# Camel - Use previously set property as a parameter to method

Tags: java, reflection, apache-camel, orchestration

Using Camel 3.5.0.

I need to set a value to a property and, after some transformation, use that property as a parameter in a method call throught the method `bean`, from Camel.

```
from("direct:route1")
        .setProperty("myProperty", method(MyBean.class, "myMethod"))
        .transform(method(transformerBean, "transformMethod"))
        .bean(MyBean.class,
                "otherMethod(<<HERE I WANT TO PASS THE PREVIOUSLY SET PROPERTY 'myProperty'>>)")
        .to("direct:route2");
```

There is an alternative. Instead of using the `setProperty` method, if I use the `setHeader`, also from Camel, the way to use that header as a parameter is `${headers.nameOfHeaderKey}`. That works as a charm. But when I try to use the Property feature, I am not getting a way to retrieve it and pass it as a method param.

In other words, when I try this: `${properties.myProperty}` I get this error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.camel.language.simple.types.SimpleParserException: Unknown function: properties.myProperty
    at org.apache.camel.language.simple.ast.SimpleFunctionExpression.createSimpleExpression(SimpleFunctionExpression.java:247)
    at org.apache.camel.language.simple.ast.SimpleFunctionExpression.createExpression(SimpleFunctionExpression.java:54)
    at org.apache.camel.language.simple.ast.SimpleFunctionStart.doCreateLiteralExpression(SimpleFunctionStart.java:69)
    at org.apache.camel.language.simple.ast.SimpleFunctionStart.createExpression(SimpleFunctionStart.java:59)
    at org.apache.camel.language.simple.SimpleExpressionParser.createExpressions(SimpleExpressionParser.java:164)
    at org.apache.camel.language.simple.SimpleExpressionParser.doParseExpression(SimpleExpressionParser.java:87)
    at org.apache.camel.language.simple.SimpleExpressionParser.parseExpression(SimpleExpressionParser.java:54)
    ... 98 common frames omitted
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Syntax for Exchange Property is `${exchangeProperty.myProperty}`.

See [Simple language docs](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/languages/simple-language.html):

> exchangeProperty.foo | Object | refer to the foo property on the exchange

Comment: Just perfect. Thank you!!